# How to get a number between double underscores in a string and multiply it with another number?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Let's say i have an example string,

```js
let str = "Congrats! ID: 342, your salary is increased by __5%__ and it will increase by __10%__ next month.";
```

I need to get the numbers which are between double underscores (Ex: __5%__ and __10%__ as shown above) and multiply them with 2.
So my output should be,

```js
let result = "Congrats! ID: 342, your salary is increased by __10%__ and it will increase by __20%__ next month.";
```

Note: The number 342 should remain same as it's not between double underscore.

How can i get this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any code attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.replace()` with a callback function like this:

```js
let str = "Congrats! ID: 342, your salary is increased by __5%__ and it will increase by __10%__ next month.";

let res=str.replace(/__(\d+)%__/g,function(_,num){return "__"+(2*num)+"%__"});
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

- You could split your str by pattern "__".
- Check the str if it ends with "%", if it does, just multiply it twice.
- And join the array again with the same pattern.

```
  str
  .split("__")
  .map(maybeNumber => {
    if (maybeNumber.endsWith("%")) {
      return `${parseInt(maybeNumber) * 2}%`
    }

    return maybeNumber;
  })
  .join("__")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Congrats! ID: 342, your salary is increased by __5%__ and it will increase by __10%__ next month.";

var idInString = str.match(/\d+/)[0];
str = str.replace(idInString,""); // result is "Congrats! ID: , your salary is increased by __5%__ and it will increase by __10%__ next month." Now, with the first number at the beginning of string. Now, we can use the same method to get the other two numbers.

var firstNumberInString = str.match(/\d+/)[0];
document.write(firstNumberInString*2+"%"); // results in "10%"

str = str.replace(firstNumberInString,""); 

var secondNumberInString = str.match(/\d+/)[0];
document.write(secondNumberInString*2+"%"); // results in "20%"
```